# $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ generated by one-parameter unipotent subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, dynamical-systems

On the [page 4 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603483.pdf), it indicates that **$\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is generated by one-parameter unipotent subgroups**. I wonder how to prove this fact. By definition, a unipotent matrix is the one whose only eigenvalues are $1$'s and a unipotent subgroup is the image of a map $t\to u_t$ where $u_t$ is unipotent for all $t\in \mathbb R$.

I remember that $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is generated by three types of elements
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & a^{-1} \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The last two types of elements are clearly unipotent by definition but the first one is not necessarily unipotent.

So how to see that $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is generated by one-parameter unipotent subgroups. Or did I misunderstand the paper?

Comment: Isn't $SL(n,k)$ generated by transvections in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $a=1+x$, then $$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac{x}{a}\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-a&1\end{pmatrix}$$